# Const keyword not recognized by MonkeyC

Tags: connectiq, monkeyc

I am building project in monkeyc (ConnectIq) from Garmin in Eclipse, and I want to use `const` instead of `var` in my code, but it seems that the `const` keyword is not recognized by the compiler. What could be wrong?

My code is:

```
const PI = 3.14;
```

Compiler complain like this:

```
BUILD: ERROR: C:\Path:155  missing '}' at 'const'
```

If I change `const` to `var`, everything goes well. Where can be a problem? From Garmin documentation MonkeyC should have`const` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that `const` keyword cannot be inside a function, it has to be as a class variable. Then it works. I just do not know if it is a bug or a feature.

Answer (score 5):

It is neither a bug nor a feature, it is just the way that the language is implemented. The [Programmer's Guide](https://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/programmers-guide/monkey-c#constants) explicitly says

> Constants are named, immutable values declared with the `const` keyword. These are useful for storing unchanging values that may be used repeatedly throughout code. **Constants must be declared at the module or class level; they cannot be declared within a function**.